# undefined reference to opEquals: Linker errors with Derelict3 Bindings to SDL2

Tags: sdl, d, sdl-2, derelict3

I am trying to write a simple hello world using the Derelict3 bindings for SDL2. I am getting errors during linking that I have not seen before.

```
module main;

import derelict.sdl2.sdl;

pragma(lib, "DerelictSDL2");
pragma(lib, "DerelictUtil");
pragma(lib, "dl");

int main(string[] args)
{
    DerelictSDL2.load();
    return 0;
}
```

**command line:**

> dmd src/main.d -debug -Iinclude -Isrc
>   -L-Llib -L-lSDL2

**output:**

```
> lib/libDerelictSDL2.a(sdl_55_698.o):(.rodata+0x41e8): undefined reference to `_D6object6Object8opEqualsMFC6ObjectC6ObjectZb'
> lib/libDerelictUtil.a(exception_9b_6db.o):(.rodata+0xe8): undefined
> reference to `_D6object6Object8opEqualsMFC6ObjectC6ObjectZb'
> lib/libDerelictUtil.a(exception_9d_89d.o):(.rodata+0x178): undefined
> reference to `_D6object6Object8opEqualsMFC6ObjectC6ObjectZb'
> lib/libDerelictUtil.a(exception_9e_7a5.o):(.rodata+0x118): undefined
> reference to `_D6object6Object8opEqualsMFC6ObjectC6ObjectZb' collect2:
> ld returned 1 exit status
>         --- errorlevel 1
```

**what I have tried:**

- verify that Derelict3 and SDL2 are up-to-date
- changing the order of my linked libraries
- searching online: I could only find 1 other post related to this: http://dblog.aldacron.net/forum/index.php?topic=834.0

I am using DMD64 D Compiler v2.063.2.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like Derelict was built using a different version of D than the one you're using to build your program. Try rebuilding Derelict from source.

Comment: I did rebuild Derelict with the same compiler, but then I discovered that the Derelict build script was not removing the old libraries, so the problem was that I was still linking against old libraries.